# Beam on EMR throws a java.util.ServiceConfigurationError

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, amazon-emr

I have an Apache Beam application(using beam version **2.23.0**) that I am trying to deploy on AWS EMR(**emr-5.30.1**) with Flink(1.10.0) preinstalled.

The application is running with no issues when I deploy it on my local docker flink cluster. But when I do

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster -c my_class my_jar.jar
```

on the master node of the EMR cluster

I get

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findModules(ObjectMapper.java:1054)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.<clinit>(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:471)
at org.myapp.main(MainApp.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:321)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:205)
at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:138)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:664)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:213)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:895)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:968)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:968)
```

Seems like the issue is with
`org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.<clinit>(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:471)` but I am not clear on what is causing this behaviour.

Can someone please advise what may cause this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This looks like a classloading issue to me. Can you find all jars in the classpath where the class `JaxbAnnotationModule` is in? Do you have it into your jar as well?

Comment: hi @ArvidHeise there is no `JaxbAnnotationModule` in my class path, you are correct. What confuses me though is why is my application working fine on the local docker setup though? It is the same JAR that I am deploying at both places and for some reason EMR is failing and the local not. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably a classloading issue.

On EMR Flink EC2 instance, there are already some jars, and these libraries are loaded before your own dependencies. So, the version that is used at runtime is the one provided by EMR, not the one you have as a dependency in your own `pom.xml`.

There are multiple solutions:

- in your `pom.xml`, use the same version than the one provided by EMR
- in EC2 instance, replace the EMR version by yours
- change the order of library loading
- whatever the solution, you need to send to Flink all the required dependencies, no only the jar that contains your own code

Comment: Thank you. Yes the issue was indeed in the version mismatch.